# Star shiny app in the background and use values of global environment

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application that I deployed as a library. `library(covid)`

My application creates a JSON file. The user interacts in the shiny app and this json file is being written in real time.

To start,

1. I created a function called `launch_app(fileName)`   which receives the name of my json file.

**launch_app(fileName)**

```
launch_app <- function(fileName) {
  fileName <<- fileName
  appDir <- system.file("myapp", package = "covid")
  shiny::runApp(appDir, display.mode = "normal")
  return(fileName)
}
```

As you can see I set the fileName variable as a **global variable** in order to be used in my shinyapp.

2. This is my shiny app

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
ui <- htmlTemplate("www/covid.html",
       text_output = tableOutput("table2")
)

server <-  function(input, output, session){
    wd <- getOption("wd")
    path_file <- file.path(wd, paste0(fileName, ".json"))

    # This block fires each time we receive a message from JavaScript
    output$table2 <- renderTable({

        #Write json file
        json_value = input$jsonData
        write(json_value, file.path(wd, paste0(fileName, ".json")))

    })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui , server)
```

So far if I tried my function and everything works fine, My app received the fileName value and then a json file is stored on my computer.

But everything changes when I tried to **run my app in the background**

**What I need?**

I need to run my app in the background, I tried to do this running a local job but the issue is that the fileName value is not being recognized by the application.
Other alternativa that I tried it was running this command `R -e "shiny::runApp('inst/myapp/app.R')"`  but the same issue: the fileName doesn't exist.

How other alternative or why this is not working?

Thank you
`

Comment: You didn't include the `options(wd = getwd())` part in the `launch_app` function from the last answer you received about this question. That needs to be included before you run `runApp()` otherwise the `getOption("wd")` value you call later will never be set.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the issue. The problem starts when I try to run the app in the background. How can I pass the variable fileName to the shiny app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my answer to your previous question, I gave a way to pass the working directory to the app, using `options` and `getOption`. You can apply the same technique:

```
launch_app <- function(fileName) {
  options(filename = fileName, wd = getwd())
  appDir <- system.file("myapp", package = "covid")
  shiny::runApp(appDir, display.mode = "normal")
}
```

and in the app:

```
server <-  function(input, output, session){
    wd <- getOption("wd")
    fileName <- getOption("filename")
    ......
```